# unable to format usb 1204 [daemon inhibited ]

Tags: format, usb-drive

i try to format my usb 1st time its work all data gone but i can't save any file at this usb .

[image]

then i try to check is it working or broken  here the report

[image]

```
santos@santos:~$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for santos: 

Sorry, try again.

[sudo] password for santos: 

Checking blocks 0 to 7824383

Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errdone                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
santos@santos:~$ sudo badblocks -v -w /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for santos: 

Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for santos: 

/dev/sdb is apparently in use by the system; it's not safe to run badblocks!
santos@santos:~$
```

how to format and fix this issues?

i have read 
this link 
[Formatting Pen Drive causes 'Daemon Is Inhibited' Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43967/formatting-pen-drive-causes-daemon-is-inhibited-error)

and it said like this when i try to move any items from desktop " the destination is read only 
[image] 
also in this case i use google and find this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1955353 article as same its 
not helped

following user13509 suggestion ..

[image]

while im check my chmod setting for the usb .. i found it like this

> santos@santos:/media$ sudo chmod -R 777/media/New\ Volume chmod:
>   missing operand after `777/media/New Volume' Try`chmod --help' for
>   more information.
>
> root@santos:/media# ls -l total 4 drwx------ 3 santos santos 4096 Jan 
>   1  1970 New Volume

Comment: with what filesystem were you trying to format the usb (via disk-utility)? I had the same issue today.

Comment: Please see this question to disable U3. Some of the trouble may be that you are trying to write to the wrong partition on the USB stick. After you disable U3 unplug it and plug it back in.

Comment: how to disable the U3 and what is it ?

Comment: Perhaps some more info could be necessary. Unplug you USB drive and plug it again. From a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t)type the following 5 commands: "dmesg | tail -n 20" "dmesg | grep -i usb" "dmesg | grep -i hcd" "lsusb" and "lsmod | grep -i usb". Paste everything to http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Salvador here its http://paste.ubuntu.com/1226898/

Comment: According to that paste, the filesystem on the drive is bad. Erasing it and formatting it with a new filesystem should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> sudo killall udisks

then load gparted - format to desired file system

good luck Mal

Comment: not help bro any other suggestion .. what to do .. i have updates the error screen shot at the post

Answer (score 0):

If you need to format a drive and nothing else is working then the last-ditch solution is to use `dd`. `dd` is a tool that reads bits and writes bits - very straight forward.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

This will overwrite the MBR of the drive and the next time you plug it in you will have to re-initialize the MBR with `gparted` or similar tool.

*Note: Use `/dev/sdb` not `/dev/sdb1`.*

Comment: how to use dd.dd  ? and it say like this 


 sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 5.9858e-05 s, 8.6 MB/s

Comment: This string `1+0 records in 1+0 records out 512 bytes (512 B) copied, 5.9858e-05 s, 8.6 MB/s` means it worked. It copied 512 bytes worth of zeros overtop of your MBR.

Comment: You can now use `gparted` to make a new filesystem on it and begin using it like normal. Use `FAT` to make it useable in Windows, Mac OS, and Linux. Use `EXT` if you only want to use it on Linux.

Answer (score -2):

When formating a disk from Gparted to ext3, you run it from root user. So you need to give back the rights to appropriate users.

```
$ sudo chown santos:santos /media/USB_key_name_here -R
```

Comment: Its give me this responds .. 

chown: cannot access `/media/New Volume/.Trash-1000': Input/output error


chown: changing ownership of `/media/New Volume/': Read-only file system

Comment: Format the USB stick with Gparted again before to chown. Or empty the trash?

Comment: Formatting with Gparted should have no problem accessing it. Because, Every formatting is done with administrative rights on every OS. We format USBs in Linux and use them in Windows. This is not correct

Comment: to mr anwar and sebf . scroll up and see what you can see . that the same screen what i got it . and i do post it to have an answer how to fix it asap got it man ?

Comment: @santosamaru Is your santos user a _sudoer_ user? Try `sudo -l`. It will tell you which rights you have or if you aren't listed into the sudoer file.

Comment: @Anwar You're right I don't notice that he was trying to use ntfs. I told this about ext3.

Comment: @Anwar well to answer your question i have upload a video here its http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=2YWHOYvrKls

n for Sebf Matching Defaults entries for santos on this host:
    env_reset,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User santos may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

this the result you want to see .